# How do I 'show' a list, and then 'hide' the list with a click of a button?

Tags: jquery

This is what I have so far in terms of HTML and jquery... In a perfect world the 'list' would be hidden to start with, once the 'button' is clicked it would show. Once the 'hide' 'button' is clicked the list would 'hide' to original state.

```
<ul class="list">
<li><a href="sleeping.html">Sleeping</a></li>   
<li>Running</li>
<li>Playing with Pepper</li>
<li>Swimming</li>
<li>Lounging</li>
</ul>
<button>List</button>

$("button").click(function() {
if ($(".list").toggle().is(":visible")) {
$("button").text("Show List");
} else {
$("button").text("Hide List");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  if ($(".list").toggle().is(":hidden")) {
    $("button").text("Show List");
  } else {
    $("button").text("Hide List");
  }
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="sleeping.html">Sleeping</a>
  </li>
  <li>Running</li>
  <li>Playing with Pepper</li>
  <li>Swimming</li>
  <li>Lounging</li>
</ul>
<button>Show List</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Obviously I'm a rookie at this coding game.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and toggle that:

```
$("button").on('click', function() {
  $(".list").toggleClass('hidden');
  if ($(".list.hidden").length) {
    $(this).text("Show List");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Hide List");
  }
}).text("Show List");
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="list hidden">
  <li><a href="sleeping.html">Sleeping</a></li>
  <li>Running</li>
  <li>Playing with Pepper</li>
  <li>Swimming</li>
  <li>Lounging</li>
</ul>
<button>List</button>
```